# How can I run commands locally after running ssh commands in a shell script?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting

I'm trying to write a shell script on Ubuntu 16.04 that will execute a command on another machine remotely, then execute more commands locally. I've tried this and it doesnt work

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh username@10.200.31.131 'pkill iperf'
ssh -f username@10.200.31.131 'iperf -s'

iperf -c 10.150.91.175 >iperflog.txt
```

It will execute the first 2 commands on the remote server but I think it is also trying to execute the last command on the remote server as well and I want to execute the last one on the local server. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: the commands **are** running one at a time, so the remote `iperf` has finished before the local one gets started. I don't think that is what you want. Maybe you need to run the remote `ssh` in the background, i.e. ` ssh -f user@..... 'iperf -s'&` . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should have mentioned - the 'iperf -s' command will run the iperf server perpetually until it is stopped

Comment: please try `ssh -f user@... 'iperf -s'&` . I think it will solve your problem. There is no way that the last cmd (local `iperf`) is running on the remote machine. You can see what is happening in your shell script by turning on shell debugging/trace with `set -vx` near the top of the script. Without the `&`, you'll see that the last command never executes while, if you start the first `iperf` w `&`, then you'll see the last command execute. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your command stay Logged In!

Try to add a `; /bin/bash` to the end of your command line on the remote side

```
ssh username@10.200.31.131 'pkill iperf; /bin/bash -i'
```

i hope help you